# Como testar arrays inteiros em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Boa noite!

Preciso criar uma função que aceite um array de números e que retorne *true* se ele contiver pelo menos um número par e *false*, caso contrário.

O código abaixo até faz isso, SQN:

```
var ParOuImpar = function(num){
    var i, condicao;
    var True = "True", False = "False";


    for(i=0; i<num.length; i++){

        if ((num[i] % 2) == 0) {
                condicao = True;
            }
        else if ((num[i] % 2) != 0) {
            condicao = False;
        }

    }

    return condicao;
};
```

Alguns testes, realizados no console do Chrome:

**Quando todos os números são pares.**

ParOuImpar([6,6,6]);
"True"

**Quando todos os números são impares.**

ParOuImpar([1,1,1,1,1,1]);
"False"

**Quando um único número é par e deveria aparecer *true*.**

ParOuImpar([16,1,1,1,1, 1]);
"False"

**Quando existe um único número impar e deveria aparecer *true*, pois todos os outros são pares.**

ParOuImpar([6,6,6,7]);
"False"

**Quando o último e o primeiro número do vetor são pares.**

ParOuImpar([16,1,1,1,1, 16]);
"True"

Entendi que a função precisa analisar todo o vetor e depois verificar se ele tem pelo menos um número para e retornar verdadeiro ou falso, mas não estou sabendo codificar isso.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu laço está retornando se o *último* elemento é par ou ímpar, já que o valor da variável `condicao` está sendo modificado para cada elemento (note que se você passar um array vazio, a função retornará `undefined`). Se você quer que a função retorne `true` se existir qualquer número par, então você pode fazer exatamente isso - quando achar o primeiro número par, retorne `true`. Se o laço (`for`) terminar, quer dizer que não há nenhum número par no array, então você pode retornar `false`.

```
var ParOuImpar = function(num){
    for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if ((num[i] % 2) == 0) {
            return "True";
        }
    }

    return "False";
}
```

Exemplo no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9tay0hn/

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

#### Existe uma alternativa mais "funcional" para a solução desse problema.

Utilizando o método `every` que checa se todos os valores de um array respeitam determinada condição:

```
const hasPair = (arr) => (
    !arr.every((e) => e % 2 === 1)
);
```

E você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
hasPair([1, 1, 1]); // false
hasPair([1, 1, 2]); // true
```

Dessa maneiro o código fica mais limpo e o número de efeitos colaterais diminuem.

[Clique aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) para saber mais sobre o  método `every`: